# Class methods accessible in Rails console but not in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed the `rinku gem https://github.com/vmg/rinku`

I can then:

`rails c`

and execute a command like:
`Rinku.auto_link('This is some text with link: http://hello.com', mode=:all, 'target="_blank"', skip_tags=nil)` right in the console.

But the same command won't work in `after_save` in `class Post < ActiveRecord::Base`

`uninitialized constant Post::Rinku`

How do I access the class methods in Rinku in my `Post` `after_save` filter?

Comment: try with `::Rinku` or add `require 'rails_rinku'` to the model.

Comment: I tried ::Rinku and include and extends type things

Comment: ::Rinku gives `NameError: uninitialized constant Rinku`

Comment: what about `require 'rails_rinku'`?

Comment: `cannot load such file -- rails_rinku` I put that right under class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: Did you try to restart the server? The gem probably isnt loaded into your current rails server session.

Comment: Isn't rinku a view helper? Do you have good reason to use that from your model?

Comment: But you could try `include RailsRinku` inside the model and then invoke `rinku_auto_link` instead. Possibly need to `require 'rinku'` as well

Comment: Too many beers last night. I also haven't added a gem to the project in so long. anyway. Yes, @Jeff ... needed to restart the server. Duh. Embarrassed. I was so confused why it wasn't working...